# pg_dump on a specific schema outputs no tables and no data

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, postgresql-14

```
mydb=# select version();
                                                     version                                                      
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 14.2 (Debian 14.2-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

I have a strange issue where pg_dump on a specific schema outputs no tables and no data at all.
This is the pg_dump command and output when executed from postgres user:

```
pg_dump -n periods -d mydb
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 14.1 (Debian 14.1-1.pgdg110+1)
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 14.1 (Debian 14.1-1.pgdg110+1)

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

Notice that the tables were not dumped.

And this is my cmd to list all tables for this periods schema:

```
psql -d mydb -c '\dt+ periods'
Schema  |        Name         | Type  |  Owner   | Persistence | Access method |    Size    |                                                   Description                   >
---------+---------------------+-------+----------+-------------+---------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
 periods | for_portion_views   | table | postgres | permanent   | heap          | 0 bytes    | 
 periods | foreign_keys        | table | postgres | permanent   | heap          | 8192 bytes | A registry of foreign keys using periods WITHOUT OVERLAPS
 periods | periods             | table | postgres | permanent   | heap          | 64 kB      | The main catalog for periods.  All "DDL" operations for periods must first take >
 periods | system_time_periods | table | postgres | permanent   | heap          | 80 kB      | 
 periods | system_versioning   | table | postgres | permanent   | heap          | 88 kB      | A registry of tables with SYSTEM VERSIONING
 periods | unique_keys         | table | postgres | permanent   | heap          | 8192 bytes | A registry of UNIQUE/PRIMARY keys using periods WITHOUT OVERLAPS
```

I wonder what did I miss in order to do a successful pg_dump that also includes the periods schema ?

The periods schema comes from using this extension https://github.com/xocolatl/periods

**--- new edits after discussions in the comment section ---**

When doing create extension, the tables for that extension get created, but with empty data. My assumption is that invoking the extension's functions in live db populates the periods.* tables, and the data was not carried over into the dump, which causes the extension to error in my testing-application after a full restore.

After a good pointer from both @jjanes and @LaurenzAlbe on  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-extensions.html#EXTEND-EXTENSIONS-CONFIG-TABLES, I checked that both github.com/xocolatl/periods/blob/master/periods--1.1.sql and github.com/xocolatl/periods/blob/master/periods--1.2.sql have the pg_extension_config_dump call.

And this might be irrelevant, but from my select * from pg_extension, it shows that the periods is still at 1.1 version. I tried alter extension periods update;, it says version is already at 1.1. I tried SELECT * FROM pg_available_extension_versions WHERE name ='periods';, it lists 1.0 and 1.1 version.

Below is further information on my system:

```
Linux localdebian 4.19.0-18-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.208-1 (2021-09-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux
Debian 10 Buster

# dpkg -L postgresql-14-periods
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/postgresql
/usr/lib/postgresql/14
/usr/lib/postgresql/14/lib
/usr/lib/postgresql/14/lib/bitcode
/usr/lib/postgresql/14/lib/bitcode/periods
/usr/lib/postgresql/14/lib/bitcode/periods/periods.bc
/usr/lib/postgresql/14/lib/bitcode/periods.index.bc
/usr/lib/postgresql/14/lib/periods.so
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/postgresql-14-periods
/usr/share/doc/postgresql-14-periods/README.md.gz
/usr/share/doc/postgresql-14-periods/changelog.Debian.amd64.gz
/usr/share/doc/postgresql-14-periods/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/postgresql-14-periods/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/postgresql-14-periods/copyright
/usr/share/doc/postgresql-doc-14
/usr/share/doc/postgresql-doc-14/extension
/usr/share/doc/postgresql-doc-14/extension/README.periods.gz
/usr/share/postgresql
/usr/share/postgresql/14
/usr/share/postgresql/14/extension
/usr/share/postgresql/14/extension/periods--1.0--1.1.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/14/extension/periods--1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/14/extension/periods--1.1--1.2.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/14/extension/periods--1.1.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/14/extension/periods--1.2.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/14/extension/periods.control
/usr/share/doc/postgresql-14-periods/README.periods.gz

# select * from pg_extension where extname = 'periods';
   oid   | extname | extowner | extnamespace | extrelocatable | extversion |                     extconfig                     |    extcondition     
---------+---------+----------+--------------+----------------+------------+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------
 2406036 | periods |       10 |         2200 | f              | 1.1        | {2406063,2406069,2406089,2406101,2406114,2406137} | {"","","","","",""}
(1 row)

# alter extension periods update;
NOTICE:  version "1.1" of extension "periods" is already installed
ALTER EXTENSION

# SELECT * FROM pg_available_extension_versions WHERE name ='periods';
  name   | version | installed | superuser | relocatable | schema |   requires   |                               comment                                
---------+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------+--------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------
 periods | 1.0     | f         | t         | f           |        | {btree_gist} | Provide Standard SQL functionality for PERIODs and SYSTEM VERSIONING
 periods | 1.1     | t         | t         | f           |        | {btree_gist} | Provide Standard SQL functionality for PERIODs and SYSTEM VERSIONING
(2 rows)
```

Comment: I think i messed up during dump and restore. Now that i retried it again with minimum options on both pg_dump and pg_restore, everything is okay. Even the periods.* are dumpable. I'm closing this question now.

Answer (score 3):

Tables owned by extensions do not ordinarily get dumped.  They would presumably get re-created when the extension itself was.

There is [a way to override that](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-extensions.html#EXTEND-EXTENSIONS-CONFIG-TABLES) but your extension apparently does not.

When overridden, still the data is dumped only when the CREATE EXTENSION itself is also dumped, which does not happen under `-n`.  Belonging to an extension basically overrides belonging to a schema.

Comment: even when I explicitly dump that specific schema using pg_dump ```-n``` switch ?

Comment: Yes, even then. But that is what you want, since the tables get created by the extension anyway. However, [you can tell PostgreSQL to dump the table data](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-extensions.html#EXTEND-EXTENSIONS-CONFIG-TABLES).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I tried adding ```--extensions=periods -n periods``` on a sample db and the periods extension's data was dumped correctly. I'm currently doing a full pg_dump from live server without -n switch but with --extensions specified for periods and still trying to bring and restore it in my local debian before further updating it here.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Yes the tables get created, but with empty data. My assumption is that invoking the extension's functions in live db populates the periods.* tables, and the data was not carried over into the dump, which causes the extension to error in my testing-application after a full restore.

Comment: Follow the link in my comment. It is not about how you dump the data, it is about how you define the extension.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I just followed your link, and checked that both https://github.com/xocolatl/periods/blob/master/periods--1.1.sql and https://github.com/xocolatl/periods/blob/master/periods--1.2.sql have the ```pg_extension_config_dump``` call. And this might be irrelevant, but from my ```select * from pg_extension```, it shows that the periods is still at 1.1 version. I tried ```alter extension periods update;```, it says version is already at 1.1. I tried ```SELECT * FROM pg_available_extension_versions WHERE name ='periods';```, it lists 1.0 and 1.1 version.

Comment: Please add all that information to the question, then you could get an answer.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I added more details on the original question per your suggestion, thank you !

Comment: I just tried with a self-created extension, and if I dump the whole database, the data from the table get dumped correctly. I am too lazy to reproduce it with your extension, but in principle it works. Perhaps open an issue with the extension.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: Thank you so much for your time, and I am copying the large dump with the ```--extensions``` switch at the moment. If this were to be problematic also, I will try dumping the whole db as you suggested -- which I tried earlier, but I might be making mistakes with ```--clean --exit-on-errors``` switch and the manual ```create extension periods cascade``` when error happened. I am beginning to think to skip ```--exit-on-errors``` later in my restore testing.